# DataAnnotation Atributes not applied in EF7

Tags: database-migration, entity-framework-core

When i migrate a database using k ef migration add bla bla. command the data annotation attributes are not reflected to the created database

e.g. iam using the [MaxLength(2)] attribute and am getting a column with data type nvarchar(MAX) created

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Annotations are not yet implemented in EF7. See issue [#107](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107).