# DataAnnotations in Mvc 6 and Entityframework 7-beta 4

Tags: entity-framework-core

How to use Dataannotation attributes in mvc 6 with entityframework 7 beta4?

I am not able to use dataannotation attributes such as required, Key,StringLength,MaxLength etc in data model for entityframework code first migration.

I added stringLength(45) in model and getting as nvarchar(max) in table instead of nvarchar(45).

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataAnnotation Atributes not applied in EF7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27924491/dataannotation-atributes-not-applied-in-ef7)

Comment: the DataAnnotation has not been implemented yet. even not in beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

DataAnnotations (most) will be available in beta6

Answer (score 0):

> **In Progress**
>
> The following features are currently being implemented. Some scenarios may work, but there are significant limitations as the work is incomplete.
>
> Modeling
>
> **Data annotations** are attributes that can be added to your entity classes/properties and will influence the EF model (i.e. adding [Required] will let EF know that a property is required).

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap)